# WPF DI with DbContext per form

Tags: design, dependency-injection, wpf, efcore

Trying to figure out how to keep class methods clean, follow EF's guidance of short-lived DbContexts, and use DI in WPF.  Issue I'm having is implementing transactions with DI.  I'm trying to figure out what the best way of handling this:

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public Repository(MyDbContext dataContext) { /* blah */ }

    public void Add(BLLEntity entity) { /* blah */ }

    public void GetById(int id) { /* return entity */ }
}

public class NonTransactionalAppService
{
    public AppService(IRepository repo) { /* blah */ }

    public AddNewAccount(Account account)  // Issue: Not transactional
    {
        // do some stuff....
        repo.Add(account);
    }
}

public class TransactionalAppService
{
    public TransactionalAppService(IRepositoryFactory repoFactory, DbContextFactory factory) { /* blah */ }

    public AddNewAccount(Account account)  // Issue: Transactional, but odd?? And requires me to create the repositories with every call.
    {
        using (var db = factory.Create()
        {
            IRepo repo = repoFactory.Create(db);
            repo.Add(account);
        }
    }
}
```

So how do I handle transactions, keep DI for better unit-testing, and inject only what's needed without injecting factories everywhere?

This is for a desktop WPF app and I do not want to use a DI framework.

EF has guidance to use one DbContext per form, but how would I handle that with the Composition Root?  I would assume I would need some type of FormFactory that would create a form and inject all the required dependencies to include the DbContext.

Comment: Change Repository to take `ContextFactory` as  dependency instead of `DbContext`, then repository will create context whenever it need and as much as required

Comment: Are you basically asking how to handle Unit of Work? It looks to me you need to abstract the context out and pass that around like what Fabio says. Not sure what you are asking exactly.

Comment: @Fabio, this doesn’t allow me to use transaction then. So I can’t do batch updates and rollbacks when multiple repositories are involved. For example let’s say a new account needs to be added. The could involved a row being added to multiple tables. Therefore multiple repositories are involved. If the transaction fails then I don’t want to leave any of the tables in an inconsistent state. I used to use a context factory in the repository and it worked okay, not the best.

Comment: @Sentinel, I don’t think abstracting away the Context into a UnitOfWork will necessarily solve my issue. I want to use DI with a new context per form or per transaction. The service layer (an application service) should be responsible to handle a transaction. But right now I’m having trouble handling transactions and injecting contexts into the repository using constructor injection.

Comment: Why you cannot gather all required data and pass it to one repository method, which will save data to multiply tables with one context and one call of `SaveChanges()`?

Comment: @Fabio, what if there is more than one aggregate root involved? This would not make sense to have my repository so coarse that it writes to multiple tables. Additionally, how are you handling transactions? On a per-method basis?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4888212/1296840 I think something like this is what I’m looking for but then to inject a UofWFactory and create it with every method call to then inject it into Repositories created with a RepositoryFactory.

Comment: @keelerjr12, id you cannot save different aggregate roots without transaction - they are not "roots" any more. Your repository will save data provided by domain layer. How you will save it: in one row in one table or in different tables with transaction is implementation details of persistence layer. Your "repository" shouldn't reflect database schema, it should reflect your domain structure.

Comment: @keelerjr12, You can have `order` which contains `customer`, `order-lines`, `delivery-address` objects. How you saving them shouldn't be important from domain layer point of view. If you need save order you pass it's object/data to persistence layer and rest is implementation details of persistence layer.